# Black boxes around slider in wxpython GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I imagine this is a simple question and was hoping it someone would be able to help me figure it out. I have multiple wxpython sliders in my GUI but some of them have black boxes around.

The sliders are placed inside a `StaticBox` which is placed inside `ScrolledPanel`. It seems that those that are on top (i.e. are shown without the need to scroll the panel) look normal, as for the 'Annotation font size' but the ones that were hidden have black background behind it. Anyone has any ideas?

I thought it was because I was not calling `Layout()` but it doesn't make any difference.

[image]

Comment: It looks like more than one static box, post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem on my side. Maybe it helps you too. In my case, I have a lot of text boxes and sliders on a scrolled panel (wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):

Black boxes around sliders:
[image]

I am fixing it by setting the background color of the panel after I have finished populating it with graphic elements:

```
self.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')
```

Here is the result:

No more black boxes around sliders:
[image]